# Run-time error 13 in renaming book

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, renaming

There is book1 where in one column are the names of old books , and in another the names of new ones (old ones need to be renamed in new ones). n,m-numbers.

An error occurs:

> Run-time error ‘13’ Type mismatch in line

```
OldName = "" + n + ".xlsm"
```

Code:

```
    Sub Кл()

    Dim OldName, NewName
    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim t As Long, m As Long, n As Long


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

     Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 
           7\вспомогательные программы\Книга в лист\виз.xlsx")
     For t = 3 To 5

      n = book1.Worksheets("общ").Range("C" & t).Value
      m = book1.Worksheets("общ").Range("C" & t).Offset(0, 1).Value

      OldName = "" + n + ".xlsm"
      NewName = "" + m + ".xlsm"

      Name OldName As NewName

      OldName = "E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 
            7\вспомогательные программы\Книга в лист\Отборные 
            условия\Откуда\" + n + ".xlsm"
      NewName = "E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 
              7\вспомогательные программы\Книга в лист\Отборные 
             условия\Куда\" + m + ".xlsm"

      Name OldName As NewName

      Next t
      book1.Close

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      Application.EnableEvents = True

      End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you  Dim OldName As String?

Comment: Use `&` to concatenate strings. Otherwise Excel may be want to calculate with `+`: `OldName = "" & n & ".xlsm"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try `Dim oldName As String` as you are working with a string and then use `&` to concatenate, not `+`.

You can explicitly convert `n` with `CStr(n)` rather than let it be implicitly converted.

And what is the point of `"" +` at the start? It won't add anything. Just `Cstr(n) & ".xlsm"` should suffice.

`n` must contain the full file path as the `Name` function requires the ***location*** and the filename.

[Name statement:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/name-statement)

> **oldpathname**   Required. String expression that specifies the existing
>   file name and location — may include directory or folder, and drive.
>
> **newpathname**   Required. String expression that specifies the new file
>   name and location — may include directory or folder, and drive. The
>   file name specified by newpathname can't already exist.

Comment: This error disappeared , but the new occurs in line (first one)
    Name OldName As NewName
R-t error 53 file not found

Comment: Does the old filename exist?

Comment: Yes (1.xlsm ,4.xlsm ...)

Comment: You need the full file path in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `+` should be an `&`. line should read

```
oldname = "path\filename" & n & ".xlsm"
```

Possible `cstr(n)` or `text(n , "format")` could do the same